# Is the notion of Kali yuga "ripening (deteriorating)" present in scripture?

Tags: kali-yuga

In Tamil they say Kali is "ripening" to describe social ills - i.e., all the ills associated with the Kali Yuga getting worse.

Does scripture say that Kali Yuga is an age of steady deterioration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is present.

**Kali Yuga**

> These are the characteristics of Kaliyuga: violence, jealousy,
> falsehood, deception and slaughter of ascetics. These are the
> characteristics of Kali age which people inherit.

**Vayu Purana I.58.31**

> Affected by the traits of the Age, **entire dharma deteriorates**. It is
> doubtful whether the livelihood (of the people) can be achieved even
> by putting up mental strain, physical exertion or prayers.

**Vayu Purana I.58.32**

> In Kali Age, there are fatal diseases. There is perpetual fear of
> hunger. There is terrible danger of draught. Vision is blurred and
> rendered perverse.

**Vayu Purana I.58.33**

> In Kali age people are unrighteous, unmindful of the rules of conduct,
> fierce in anger but deficient in power and splendor. They always utter
> falsehood.

**Vayu Purana I.58.35**